# Curl to return just http status code from command line

Tags: linux, shell, curl

I have below curl which reads data from a file and post it to the sever and everything works fine. I get the response back successfully as well.

> curl -v 'url' -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br' -H
> 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'Accept: application/json' -H
> 'Connection: keep-alive' -H 'DNT: 1' -H 'Origin: url' --data-binary
> "@/Users/david/Downloads/temp.txt" --compressed

Now I am just trying to get the status code from above curl request instead of full response. I tried doing like below but it doesn't work.

> curl -v 'url' -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br' -H
> 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'Accept: application/json' -H
> 'Connection: keep-alive' -H 'DNT: 1' -H 'Origin: url' --data-binary
> "@/Users/david/Downloads/temp.txt" --compressed | head -n 1 | cut -d$'
> ' -f2

Is there anything wrong in my above command?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove `-v` and add [`--silent`](https://curl.se/docs/manpage.html#-s),
discard stdout with [`--output /dev/null`](https://curl.se/docs/manpage.html#-o)
and print the http status with [`--write-out '%{http_code}'`](https://curl.se/docs/manpage.html#-w) (in short `-s -o /dev/null -w '%{http_code}'`):

```
curl 'url' \
  -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -H 'Accept: application/json' \
  -H 'Connection: keep-alive' \
  -H 'DNT: 1' \
  -H 'Origin: url' \
  --data-binary "@/Users/david/Downloads/temp.txt" \
  --compressed \
  --silent \
  --output /dev/null \
  --write-out '%{http_code}'
```

Comment: Thank you! It makes sense now. I was doing wrong way I guess.